# gprofng vs kcachegrind, better experience

Tags: performance, caching, comparison, valgrind

Question is closed for some ridiculous reason. Clearly an admin earning stars or some activity related points system.
Stack overflow just getting WORSE and WORSE!!

Reddit, here I come

part from the respective marketing  blurb, Im not seeing anything that does a comparison of KcacheGrind Vs gprofng. Has anybody out there an opinion? I'm leaning towards kcachegrind as I use Valgrind already (same author).

Thanks much

Graham

Comment: What is the difference between `gprofng` and `perf`?

Comment: https://parallel.computer/presentations/PPoPP2023/2023-Ruud-Slides.pdf

slide 14.

Comment: I had a look for gprofng. It looks interesting. I was a Solaris user for a long time, and knew well the old Sun Studio compilers, which contained the original version of this tool. Really pleased that it is being open sourced and won't just become abandonware.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. `kcachegrind` is a profiling results viewer. `gprofng` is a profiling tool.

`cachegrind` is quite different from tools like `gprofng` I'll ignore the programmable CPU counters and assume that you just want time-based profiling.

- `cachegrind` has a high overhead
- `cachegrind` has accurate and reproducible instruction counts, but the cache emulation is poor (and no longer enabled by default in the latest versions).
- `gprofng` uses statisitical sampling
- `gprofng` needs to run for a reasonably long time (at least a few minutes) to get enough sample data to be meaningful